# What is the physical interpretation of inductors and capacitors equations in Frequency(s) domain?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, network

s-domain modelling of capacitor and inductor equation:

*V(s)=LsI(s)−Li(0−)*

*I(s)=CsV(s)−Cv(0−)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the LaPlace operator, 's' is the equivalence of derivative in the time domain then:

**For the first equation** the voltage is equal to the inductance, $L$ times the rate of change in current less any initial current through the inductor.

and

**For the second equation** the current is equal to the capacitance, $C$ times the rate of change in voltage less any initial voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: Will this initial current and voltage across the inductor and capacitor respectively remain indefinitely even after  a time varying input is applied to the circuit (t>0), that is will they be always present in the equation or equivalent model?

Comment: @ShrikantMahapatra As an ideal dynamic system without resistance, no. The initial conditions will lead to perpetual oscillation in the LC circuit. As a realistic dynamic system (there's always resistance), the voltage and current will eventually decay to zero.